# Selecting, Storing, Selecting from different table

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a database that with 2 tables.

db.playerstats

```
PlayerUID | PlayerKills 
123456    | 10
234567    | 20
345678    | 33
```

AND

db.playerinfo

```
UID    |   Name
123456 |  Tom
234567 |  Joe
345678 |  Alex
```

I need to take the max value of the playerstats `PlayerKills` with the `Name` of the player in the `playerinfo` table.

I know how to pull the max

```
SELECT PlayerUID, MAX(PlayerKills) FROM db.playerstats;
```

But What I'm not understanding is the statement to store the UID from `playerstats` and return `name` from `playerinfo`.

The PlayerUID References the UID in a Key. I don't know if this makes it easier or not.

As the comment below, I am trying a join statement

```
SELECT PlayerUID, MAX(PlayerKills), Name FROM test_a3wasteland.playerstats JOIN test_a3wasteland.playerinfo ON PlayerUID = UID;
```

Clearly I know this is wrong, but how do I correlate the name with the highest value when it changes?

Update:
I tried:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(PlayerKills) FROM db.playerstats JOIN db.playerinfo ON PlayerUID = UID;
```

But it's still returning the wrong name.

Comment: use join to get the player name using playerid

Comment: edited post, can't seem to get the join statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get the name of the userid with most kills. Limit 1 will only return the top 1 record with most kills.

```
select info.name, 
          stats.PlayerKills
from test_a3wasteland.playerstats stats
inner join test_a3wasteland.playerinfo info
 on stats.PlayerUID = info.UID
order by stats.PlayerKills DESC
limit 1;
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, I think I was just over complicating it.

Comment: more power to your project.